# Assistance with apache rewrite (capture subdomain)

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I found out an issue with my WordPress installation.  If I go to https://www.mywordpress.com/wp-admin (note there is no trailing slash), I get redirected to http://www.mywordpress.com/wp-admin/ (note it went from https to http and it now has a trailing slash).  I need that trailing slash but I need it to go to https:// not http://

Here is what I have at the first section of my vhost conf file and it's not working and I don't know why.  I need to capture the subdomain b/c this is a multisite WordPress installation.  For example, [www.mywordpress.com](http://www.mywordpress.com), site2.mywordpress.com, site3.mywordpress.com, etc.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.mywordpress\.com\/wp\-admin$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://%1.mywordpress.com/wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
```

Any input/advice would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for showing your efforts in your question(keep it up). Could you please do check if your htaccess file is really active? You could enter some garbage characters eg--> `------` in your .htaccess file and then check any URL if you get 500 internal error from it, if yes then its working else its NOT enable at all, let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this one out...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /wp-admin$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
```